# Why I'm getting different UUIDs and a default int64 timestamp when consuming a kafka message?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, avro, uuid

Basically I'm producing a KAFKA message on my Golang project that has an Avro file defining the schema. Most of those is a `*string` type of field. One of this fields, the `id`, should be represented by a UUID value. There is also timestamp defined as `*int64`.The avro is defined as:

```
Event{
...
            {
                "name": "timestamp",
                "type": [
                    "null",
                    "long"
                ],
                "default": null,
                "doc": "timestamp"
            },
            {
                "name": "token",
                "type": [
                    "null",
                    "string"
                ],
                "default": null,
                "doc": "token"
            },
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": [
                    "null",
                    "string"
                ],
                "default": null,
                "doc": "id"
            },
...

id *string `avro:"id"`

Token *string `avro:"token"`

timestamp *int64 `avro:"token"`

...
```

On my application, the domain objects definition of the `id` and the `token` are pretty similar. They are reference in a complex object and are defined by:

```
package XPTO

type Token string
```

```
package XPTO

type id string
```

So finally I created an event, containing this types and sent to the KAFKA producer. Got no errors. When consuming, we use the `github.com/segmentio/kafka-go` lib. Since we use Wire Format I had to skip 5 bytes to get the avro data. So to consume:

```
    msg, err := reader.ReadMessage(context.Background())
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    response := avro.Event{}
    response.Unmarshal(msg.Value[5:])
```

The response I get is basically what I sent. However there are fields that are either partially wrong, or completely wrong.

- For the `token` field I'm getting exactly the data I sent. The assertion is completely right.
- For timestamp fields, that should come as *int64, I'm getting the same value no matter what I sent to the producer. I even sent a nil value and get the same default value.
- For UUID values I'm getting the last section, the node, equal but is the only piece that matches what I sent.

So, finally, my question is: is there some specific configuration or way to consume kafka messages for this type of values(timestamp and uuid) that I need to do?